# Data Grid in PHP

Tags: php, gridview, datagrid

I need to create a datagrid in a web application using php as the backend programming language, which will be populated from a MySQL database objects (views, stored procedures). The end user should be able to edit the data in this datagrid and the data in MySQL tables will need to get updated.

If you can give me some examples -tutrial, demos, project with explanation on how to use those with examples, it will be a great help.

Comment: To see examples, just Google for them. When you run into a specific problem, ask here.

Comment: http://phpgrid.com/ first result in google

Comment: See https://github.com/view-components/grids

Comment: It will be a 2 step work. First call mysql function to execute SP and load data in php array. Next to display it you can use grid tools like [phpgrid framework](http://www.phpgrid.org) which reading php array at once and allow search/sort on client side.

Comment: Take a look at this one, I found it useful: https://github.com/lazymofo/datagrid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use http://phpgrid.com

```
$dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM orders", "orderNumber", "orders"); 

// change column titles
$dg->set_col_title("orderNumber", "Order No.");
$dg->set_col_title("orderDate", "Order Date");
$dg->set_col_title("shippedDate", "Shipped Date");
$dg->set_col_title("customerNumber", "Customer No.");

// hide a column
$dg -> set_col_hidden("requiredDate");

// change default caption
$dg -> set_caption("Orders List");

$dg -> display();
```

examples can be found on http://phpgrid.com/example/

it's easy to use and looks pretty.

[image: data grid example]

Comment: Read question carefully, user need data from stored procedure not sql query!

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to edit the data or just display only? If just display, you should take at look at the local array data source example.

1.Return array from MySQL stored procedure, see this example:
        http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php,

2.Then use the phpGrid local array feature to display datagrid
        http://phpgrid.com/example/local_array_data_source/

That's it!

Answer (score 4):

Second phpGrid from http://phpgrid.com. I work for local school district. Trust me, we got a lot database tables to manage spread across multiple systems. phpGrid by far the best tool I've used to quickly develop web based content administration system.