# How to get the data in Grid view using Select Option in Php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to display the data when List box item is selected. Previously in Grid View all data will be there. If user selected One option that option data only should display. How to do it in Php. Here is my code

```
 <td width="5%" align="right"><b>School<b></td><td width="1%"><b>:</b></td><td width="5%" align="left">
<select name="school_id" id="school_id" class="list_box">
<option value="">Select School</option>
<?php
$school_sql=mysql_query("select * from tbl_school");
while($school=mysql_fetch_array($school_sql))
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $school['school_id'];?>" <?php if(isset($workshop_fetch['school_id']) && ($workshop_fetch['school_id']==$school['school_id'])) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> ><?php echo $school['school_name'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
 </td>
 </tr> 

  <tr class="table_txt2">
    <td width="7%">S.No</td>
    <td width="20%">School</td>
    <td width="10%">Payment Details</td>
    <td width="20%">Payment Date</td>
    <td width="13%">Amount</td>
    <td width="10%">Due Date</td>
    <td width="10%">Paid Date</td>
    <td width="10%">Is Paid</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
$slno=0;
$payment_sql=mysql_query("select * from tbl_school_payments");

while($result=mysql_fetch_array($payment_sql))
{
$slno++;

?>
<tr <?php if($slno%2==1) echo "class='table_txt3'"; else echo "class='table_txt4'"; ?> id="row_<?php echo $result['payment_id']; ?>">
<td ><?php echo $slno;?></td>
<td >
<?php
$school_sql=mysql_query("select * from tbl_school where school_id='$result[school_id]'");
$school=mysql_fetch_array($school_sql);
 echo ucwords($school['school_name']);
 ?>
</td>



//Here code for display data 
    <td ><?php echo $result['payment_details'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $result['payment_date'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $result['amount_paid'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $result['due_date'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $result['paid_date'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $result['is_paid'];?></td>

      <?php } ?>
      </table>
```

Comment: There is a solution already, read this link and there are lot more
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418873/data-grid-in-php

Comment: ok. But i want, If you observe the first lines of code there is a select option is there for school. Based on selection only that school have to display. Otherwise total Schools will be displayed. I want like this.

Comment: You can do this with AJAX or by sending a GET parameter to the same URL with the `school_id`

Comment: Could you give more explanation please @user007

Comment: I'll write up the answer using the GET method.

Comment: Please give any example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td width="5%" align="right"><b>School<b></td><td width="1%"><b>:</b></td><td width="5%" align="left">
<select name="school_id" id="school_id" class="list_box">
<option value="">Select School</option>
<?php
$school_sql=mysql_query("select * from tbl_school");
while($school=mysql_fetch_array($school_sql))
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $school['school_id'];?>" <?php if(isset($workshop_fetch['school_id']) && ($workshop_fetch['school_id']==$school['school_id'])) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> ><?php echo $school['school_name'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
 </td>
 </tr> 

  <tr class="table_txt2">
    <td width="7%">S.No</td>
    <td width="20%">School</td>
    <td width="10%">Payment Details</td>
    <td width="20%">Payment Date</td>
    <td width="13%">Amount</td>
    <td width="10%">Due Date</td>
    <td width="10%">Paid Date</td>
    <td width="10%">Is Paid</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
$slno=0;
$payment_sql=mysql_query("select * from tbl_school_payments");
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($payment_sql))
{
$slno++;

?>
<tr <?php if($slno%2==1) echo "class='table_txt3'"; else echo "class='table_txt4'"; ?> id="row_<?php echo $result['payment_id']; ?>">
<td ><?php echo $slno;?></td>
<td >
<?php
/*This IF block added
===================== */
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

    $query = "select * from tbl_school where school_id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
}
else
{
    $query = "select * from tbl_school where school_id='$result[school_id]'";
}
$school_sql=mysql_query($query);
$school=mysql_fetch_array($school_sql);
 echo ucwords($school['school_name']);
 ?>
</td>



//Here code for display data 
    <td ><?php echo $result['payment_details'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $result['payment_date'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $result['amount_paid'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $result['due_date'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $result['paid_date'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $result['is_paid'];?></td>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Script tag added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      jQuery('#school_id').change(function(e){

          selected = jQuery('#school_id').val();
          window.location = window.location.pathname + '?id=' + selected;

      });
});
```

What's basically happening is, when you select a `school_id`, the jQuery `change()` function fires and appends the selected `school_id` to the current URL and goes to it. Now the URL has a id=`school_id` value which the PHP checks before executing the query. If there is one, it uses that value in its select statement.

Is this what you needed?

Comment: could you tell me. how to do this with ajax

Comment: Yes I can, but I'm quite not sure what you are trying to display here. Can you please be a bit clear about, if a school id is selected from the dropdown, which all select queries use that school id to display only those records?