# How do i put my query results in a proper view/table

Tags: php

Hi there I have a query that displays the results of user inputted data but i want to display it in a nice table with headings. The query displays the the records with the values in the following order "id", "name", "start", "end". Im not sure how to create a nice table on the eye rather than the data js

```
<body style="background-image: url(427.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
     <div id="header"  style="background-image: url(background.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
         <img src="slot365.png"; height=220 width="470">
     </div>

<?php
    // make sure the form has actually been submitted
    // and its not just been loaded from a click on a link etc
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if ( isset($_POST['start'], $_POST['end']) ) {

            $db = new PDO('sqlite:daypilot.sqlite');

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE start > ? AND end < ?"; 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
            $stmt->execute([$_POST['start'], $_POST['end']]); 
            $events = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            $table = '<table>';
            foreach ($events as $event) {
                $table .= '<tr>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['id'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['name'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['start'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['end'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '</tr>';
            }
            $table .= '</table>';
            echo $table;
        }
    }
?>
    <form method="POST">
        1st DATE: <input type="text" name="start" /><br />
        2nd DATE: <input type="text" name="end" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Add a `<tr><th>ID</th><th> etc etc </th></tr>` above the foreach output (right below the open `<table>`). Then use CSS to style the hell out of it :)

Comment: You seem to be getting others ( i.e. US ) to do most of your work on this project and then you dont even bother to say ___thanks___ by accepting or upvoting the answers we give you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095508/user-input-dates-for-query-in-sqlite-database

Answer (score 1):

Table headings can be as simple as adding another row at the top of the table

```
<body style="background-image: url(427.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
    <div id="header"  style="background-image: url(background.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

        <img src="slot365.png"; height=220 width="470">

    </div>

<?php
    // make sure the form has actually been submitted
    // and its not just been loaded from a click on a link etc
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if ( isset($_POST['start'], $_POST['end']) ) {

            $db = new PDO('sqlite:daypilot.sqlite');

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE start > ? AND end < ?"; 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
            $stmt->execute([$_POST['start'], $_POST['end']]); 
            $events = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            $table = '<table>';

            // add a table heading
            $table .= '<thead>';
            $table .= '<tr>';
            $table .= '<th>ID</td>';
            $table .= '<th>Name</td>';
            $table .= '<th>Start Date</td>';
            $table .= '<th>End Date</td>';
            $table .= '</tr>';
            $table .= '</thead>';
            $table .= '<tbody>';

            foreach ($events as $event) {
                $table .= '<tr>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['id'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['name'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['start'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '<td>' . $event['end'] . '</td>';
                $table .= '</tr>';
            }

            $table .= '</tbody>';
            $table .= '</table>';

            echo $table;
        }
    }
?>
    <form method="POST">
        1st DATE: <input type="text" name="start" /><br />
        2nd DATE: <input type="text" name="end" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: perfect thank you it was simple code but i was placing my code in the wrong place. How would you recommend implemeting this in a grid view?

Comment: @Incrediblehat Thanks for that

Comment: Ryan: I would suggest you do a bit of research for yourself, maybe start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418873/data-grid-in-php